# Uploading profile photo to IBM Connections profile via Domino Agent

Tags: java, lotus-domino, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I am trying to update profile images from a Domino Java agent using the Connections Java API. I have followed [this guide](http://bastide.org/2014/01/28/how-to-develop-a-simple-java-integration-with-the-ibm-social-business-toolkit-sdk/) and used [this sample](https://greenhouse.lotus.com/sbt/SBTPlayground.nsf/JavaSnippets.xsp#snippet=Social_Profiles_Update_Profile_Photo) from greenhouse for inspiration.

Although I don't get any exceptions, the images are not updated. Updating the telephone number works. Strange thing is, updating the jobtitle is also not working.

What I am doing is:

**Create a basic endpoint**

```
ConnectionsBasicEndpoint endpoint = new ConnectionsBasicEndpoint();
endpoint.setUser("MY_USERNAME");
endpoint.setPassword("MY_PASSWORD");
endpoint.setUrl("MY_COMPANY_CONNECTIONS_URL");
endpoint.setForceTrustSSLCertificate(true);
```

**Get my Profile via the ProfileService and update the fields**

```
ProfileService profileService = new ProfileService(endpoint);
Profile profile = profileService.getProfile(id);
profile.setTelephoneNumber("123-123-123"); // this works
profile.setJobTitle("my title"); //this does not work
```

**And to upload an image**

```
String id = profileService.getMyUserId();
profileService.updateProfilePhoto(file, id); //file is a java.io.File
```

Has anybody experienced a similar issue? I also tried it with a user with administration rights, but that made no difference.
I am working on IBM Domino 9.0.1, IBM Connections 5.0 CR1 and I am using the latest Social Business Toolkit from openntf.

Comment: do you have any logging ? or the SystemOut.log from your connections server?

Comment: On the Domino side everything seems fine (nothing in the logs). And in the connections log (profiles, common) there's also nothing. Maybe I should change the logging level on the connections server (profils cluster) to finest?

Comment: I recommend you use CURL and test the API call out before you go down that route. http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=API+Reference#action=openDocument&res_title=Adding_a_photo_to_a_profile_ic50&content=apicontent

Comment: Thanks Paul for your input. I was able to update/delete my profile photo by using CURL. I also tried it with a small standalone Java app using Apache HttpClient and the Connections API directly and this also worked. I will have a look at the connections logs on monday again.

Comment: I tried upload photo by CURL:
`curl "https://apps.na.collabserv.com/profiles/photo.do?key=...&lastMod=..." -o log.out -v -k -u user@mail.com:password -X PUT -H "Content-Type: image/jpg" -T 1.jpg`
It returns: `The type of the photo file you provided is not supported`.
I'm really confused (this file could be successfully uploaded in SC web interface). What I'm doing wrong?